# Get the referred after .htaccess mod redirect

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am redirecting users from wildcard sub-domains to a specific sub directory using mod rewrite rule while not changing address bar url. I have done it success fully but I also need the wildcard sub-domain name to use internally.
For example if someone try `xyz.domain.com` I am redirecting him to say `domain.com/abc` and I also need that `xyz` for internal use.

I tried `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` but it returns current sub directory address. Also tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but with no success. So if anyone can help please.

My .htaccess code is given below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/domain\.com\/project\/" [P,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer doesn't work with dynamic subdomains. So in your case it wont work.

When I tested your .htaccess rules, my server sets a `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']` variable with a value of original host "xyz.domain.com".

Maybe this could help.

---

**Answer for static spesific subdomains;**

put these lines to .htaccess before your redirect condition

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz.domain.com(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=internalSubdomain:xyz]
```

then you can use `$_SERVER['internalSubdomain']` and `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_internalSubdomain']` in your php code

Comment: I have updated my question and added my current .htaccess code, I am not getting the result if use this 
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule .* - [E=internalSubdomain:^(.*)]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/domain\.com\/project\/" [P,NC,QSA]`

Comment: This doesn't work with dynamic subdomains. So in your case it wont work.

Comment: Well I need it for dynamic subdomains, otherwise if I knew from which subdomain I am redirecting I could have just hardcoded the subdomain name in my php. Anyway thanks for your help

Comment: I edited my answer. Does `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']` work for you?